# CoreData: Failed to load optimized model at path /application/~/project.app/project.momd/Project.omo'

Tags: ios, xcode9, core-data-migration

CoreData: Failed to load optimized model at path /applation/~/project.app/project.momd/Project.omo'

i am using xcode 9

Comment: please make your question clear